# Return multiple checkbox from Custom html helper in mvc 3r

Tags: html-helper

Hey friends I am building questionnaire project in mvc 3. Here i need to return textbox, group of checkbox, radio buttons etc. I have build custom html helper for rendering those by checking its type from database. For single return it works fine but for multiple return it doesn't work. 
as for example:

for single return,
    return helper.CheckBox("chk"+question_id);

In some cases i need to return multiple checkbox, multiple text box and others. 
As for example: In case of radio buttons, question type will be 2. Then from html helper i have to return 3 radio buttons
How can i proceed for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Friends I got the solution for my problem.Simply using string builder and appending the multiple checkbox i return the value.

Here i have written the sample code which return label, checkbox and textbox.

I hope following code might be helpful to others also:

public static IHtmlString RenderQuestion(this HtmlHelper helper, int question_type)
     {
            var output = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

```
              output.Append(helper.CheckBox("chk" + question_id));  

                output.Append(helper.Label(questiontext));
                output.Append(helper.TextBox("txt"+question_id));

                 return helper.Raw(output.ToString());
```

}